# userform input not always transferring to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an admin section to my website where I can update a blog using a userform I created.  I set the database datafields in phpmyadmin to "text" and my html textarea to a maxlength of 100000.  But if I try to submit an article I typed that's longer than a paragraph, it doesn't update in phpmyadmin.  It works fine for maybe 300 characters, but if it gets longer than that, it doesn't update.  Am I missing a setting somewhere?  I'm an amateur.  Do I need to use a Getquerystring function for larger amounts of data?  Or is it because I'm just doing it on a localhost?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the datatype as blob

Comment: Does your website display the results correctly? phpMyAdmin won't default to showing the full text; it shows a bit then an ellipsis. You mention that anything longer than a paragraph gets cut off which makes me think your application is not dealing well with your newline character. Show a bit of your web application code where it processes your form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at your servers settings.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

in your php.ini, there are variables like post_max_size, max_get_size, and max_input_vars.  It is possible that these settings are preventing your from using what you wish.

For example:
post_max_size = 2M 
2Mb is = 2000000 bytes